# Page is posting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am making web page using Node.js and Angular. When i started everything went as it should, but now it suddenly spams the error below:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.toString (polyfills.bundle.js:4420)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.toString (polyfills.bundle.js:4438)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.toString (polyfills.bundle.js:4438)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.toString (polyfills.bundle.js:4438)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.toString (polyfills.bundle.js:4438)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
at Function.<anonymous> (affs?addonname=LONG&clientuid=1495625557888&subID=wifi&affid=9614&subaffid=1001&href=http%3A%2F%2Fl…:9)
```

When site is doing this, its not resposive at all. But as I checking node or angular everything should be fine. I fix this problem by refreshing  page until its  stops doing this. Any help to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems you could have created an infinite loop due to change detection. Do you call some function directly in the template?

Comment: In the template Im calling only auth-guard.  Double checked, didn't loop it..

Comment: well it's impossible to tell since you have not provided any code. But seems there is something that is looping because of the error message and unresponsive browser.

Comment: can you show some of your code, on lines where bug appears?

Comment: if you allow me to guess i could assume you forget to put breaking condition for recursive call, you have some unbounded recursion some where, check your recursive functions

Comment: The thing is, this happens randomly and on all pages. Just asked a friend, to test it on his computer, there it works as it should. I will try to reinstall angular and node..